# Hide simulink model window

Tags: matlab, simulink

In my project I use MATLAB's function `sim` in a loop.

At the first call for the sim function, a Simulink model window gets open.

Is there a possibilities to make this window hidden? As this `set(f,'Visible','off');` works for plots.

Comment: `sim` doesn't make the model visible and never has.  Something else in your code is doing it, most likely a call to `open_system` somewhere.

Comment: I use only `power_analyze` in my code. Can this function do it? And how to hide window in this case?

Comment: Quite possibly, but I don't have access to that function to check.  Is it m-code or p-code?  If m-code then search it for any occurances of `open_system` and try replacing them with `load_system`.  (You may have to rehash the toolboxcache after doing that.)

Comment: It's a m-code. But it has only this inside:`if nargout == 0,
  power_analyze_prv(varargin{:});
else
  [varargout{1:nargout}] = power_analyze_prv(varargin{:});
end` and comments. But `varargin` is a built-in function and I can't open it.

Comment: So `power_analyze_prv` is the function you want to look at.

Comment: It's a p-code. I can't open it

Comment: @PhilGoddard `power_analyze` is part of SimPowerSystems, see http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/power_analyze.html.

Comment: @am304, yes I realise that.